# Replace text in a tag leaving child tag intact

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have a rather interesting issue. Content is being build dynamically and creating the following scenario.

```
<button id="something">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
    Some button text
</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is replace "some button text" while preserving the Font Awesome tag. I've tried regex and so on, but kind of stuck.

As a note, I've tried .text() and it does replace the text, but also removes the i tag too.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2482744)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** for getting all descendant including `textNode` . Iterate over the result using **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)** and update the `nodVealue`

```js
$('#something').contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType === 3)
    this.nodeValue = $.trim(this.nodeValue).length ? 'new value' : '';
    // if you want to remove the element then use 'this.remove()'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="something">
  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>
  Some button text
</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @probie : glad to help you :)